# onChange event triggered unexpectedly with modified InlineEditBox

Tags: ajax, dojo, onchange, inlineeditbox

Following this thread: [Using dijit.InlineEditBox with dijit.form.Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675466/using-dijit-inlineeditbox-with-dijit-form-select) I've been using a "fixed version" of InlineEditBox that can be seen in the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/mimercha/Vuet8/16/

The "FixedInlineEditBox" dijit triggers the "onChange" event when initialized. I'm trying to use the InlineEditBox with Ajax event and can have up to 300 inline edit boxes on the page at a time, so I'm trying to understand what is triggered the "onChange" event in FixedInlineEditBox that wasn't triggered on initialization from the original InlineEditBox:

http://jsfiddle.net/mimercha/5HUga/1/

Any suggestions on how to save the displayedValue during initialization without triggering onChange would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to my calling the `save` method from `startup` in the previous modification without further altering `save` so that it wouldn't always call `onChange`.  Unfortunately, this isn't easily possible without completely overwriting the method...

http://jsfiddle.net/kfranqueiro/Vuet8/18/